# RxJava run two observables with lists as results using result from first observable in second observable

Tags: kotlin, observable, rx-java, rx-java2

I am trying to make two api calls and combine them, assign second result to first one. At first I was thinking about using `zipWith` but for the second call I need user id from the first one's response:

```
@GET("users")
fun getUsers(): Single<List<User>>

@GET("users/{userId}/repos")
fun getUserRepositories(@Path("userId") userLogin: String): Single<List<Repository>>
```

And user object looks like this:

```
data class User(
    val id: Int,
    val login: String,
    val repositories: List<Repository>
)
```

So I would like to fetch list of users and then for every user get list of his repositories and assign those repositories to the user. I've made some research and found [solution for similar problem](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/2608) with the use of `flatMap`. Now I would like to do something like this but in my case I have list of objects as a response from first request and I don't know how to handle it in a good way. I came up with something like this for now:

```
private fun getUsers(): Single<List<User>> {
    return api.getUsers()
        .flatMap { users ->
            Single.zip(users.map { user ->
                api.getUserRepositories(user.login)
            }, { it.map {it as List<Repository> } })
                .map { repositories ->
                    users.mapIndexed { index, user ->
                        User(
                            id = user.id,
                            login = user.login,
                            repositories = repositories[index]
                        )
                    }
                }
        }
}
```

It does work but I feel that it is not the best way to do this. Does anyone know how to achieve that with better, cleaner solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `publish` method:

```
data class Repository(
    val name: String
)

data class User(
    val id: Int,
    val login: String,
    val repositories: List<Repository>
)

interface Api {
    fun getUsers(): Single<List<User>>
    fun getUserRepositories(id: Int): Single<List<Repository>>
}

fun getApi(): Api {
    TODO()
}

fun getUsers(): Single<List<User>> {
    val api: Api = getApi()

    return api
        .getUsers()
        .toObservable()
        .flatMapIterable { it }
        .publish { user ->
            Observable.zip(
                user,
                user.flatMap { user -> api.getUserRepositories(user.login).toObservable() },
                BiFunction { user, repositories ->
                    user.copy(repositories = repositories)
                }
            )
        }
        .toList()
}
```

Comment: I've already accepted your answer but now I've noticed that when using your code it is working first few times and later my app is crashing. What is strange is that error stack trace is missing in logcat so I don't know what is happening